# Scala's JSON library not working properly

Tags: java, json, scala, parsing, apache-flink

I have my Apache Flink program:

```
import org.apache.flink.api.scala._
import scala.util.parsing.json._

object numHits extends App {
    val env = ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
    val data=env.readTextFile("file:///path/to/json/file")
    val j=data.map { x => ("\"\"\""+x+"\"\"\"") }
    /*1*/ println( ((j.first(1).collect())(0)).getClass() )

    /*2*/ println( ((j.first(1).collect())(0)) ) 

    /*3*/ println( JSON.parseFull((j.first(1).collect())(0)) )
    }
```

I want to parse the input JSON file into normal scala Map and for that I am using the default `scala.util.parsing.json._` library.

The output of the first `println` statement is `class java.lang.String` which is required by the JSON parsing function.

Output of the second `println` function is the actual JSON string appended and prepended by `"\"\"\""` which is also required by the JSON parser.

Now at this point if I copy the output of the second `println` command printed in the console and pass it to the `JSON.parseFull()` function, it properly parses it.

Therefore the third `println` function should properly parse the same string passed to it but it does not as it outputs a "None" string which means it failed.

Why does this happen and how can I make it work?

Answer (score 2):

> Output of the second println function is the actual JSON string appended and prepended by "\"\"\"" which is also required by the JSON parser.

No, of course it isn't. This produces a string like `"""{}"""`, which isn't valid JSON and this properly rejected by the parser. When you write `"""{}"""` in Scala code, the quotes aren't part of the string itself, they just delimit the literal: the content of the string is `{}`, which is valid JSON.

Comment: The library only parses the json if its in  this, `"""{"name":"punit"}"""`, form. And as I mentioned in my question description, if I copy the prined output and feed it to the parser it works. But in the code it won't work and I can't figure out why. You can try this library to see for yourself.

Comment: That's what I explain in the last sentence. `"""{"name":"punit"}"""` is the same as `"{\"name\":\"punit\"}"`: it represents the string `{"name":"punit"}`, which is valid JSON and doesn't contain triple quotes. You are building a different string which does contain triple quotes.

Comment: You can see this by output of `println("""{"name":"punit"}""")`, `println("{\"name\":\"punit\"}")`, and your /*2*/. Or checking `((j.first(1).collect())(0)) == """{"name":"punit"}"""`.

Comment: Okay Alexey. Thanks for the clarification. I'll try that.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to just change

```
val j=data.map { x => ("\"\"\""+x+"\"\"\"") }
```

to

```
val j=data.map { x => x.replaceAll("\"", "\\\"") }
```

But the above code is not required as the code below will work:

```
val data=env.readTextFile("file:///path/to/json").flatMap( line => JSON.parseFull(line) )
```